# Not able to submit the form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have login form page where i validated using jquery. jquery script is checking for null values but when i entered the values it is not submittingbut i am able to see the alerts in else block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        //$(this).hide();
        var name = $.trim($("#uname").val());
        var pwd = $.trim($("#pwd").val());
        alert("Value: " + name);
        alert("Text: " + pwd);
        if(name == ''){
            alert('ssss');
            $(":input").css({
                                "background-color":"#FFCECE",
                                "border":"1px solid red"

                            });
        //  return false;
            $('form').submit(function(){
                //e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }else{
        alert('else');
            $(":input").css({
                                "background-color":"",
                                "border":""
                            });
                            alert('else2');
            $('form').submit(function(){
                alert("thanks");
                return true;
            }); 
            alert('else3');         
        }

    });
});


</script>
```

This is my Html code

```
<form action="" method="post" name="loginform">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>LOGIN PAGE</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" /></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" /></td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />     </td>
<tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where the form tag begin?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    alert("thanks");
    return true;
});
```

in your else, just `return true;`

same in your if, you don't need to

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

just `return true;`

What you're doing in your code is hooking up to the submit event of the form. If you return false or true from submit button, it'll submit the form or not.

Comment: Hi @artm it worked after i removed the both submit functions and just placed return false in if and return true in else ....:)Thanks man